# Find all installed softwares in the centos linux using python script

Tags: python, centos7

How to find a list of installed software packages in centos linux using a Python script?

Comment: Why do you need python for this? you can use `rpm -qa` or  `yum list installed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query centos packages with the *rpm* command:

```
rpm -qa
```

A python program could look like this:

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output(['rpm', '-qa'])
for package in output.split('\n'):
  print(package)
```